# Call SQL query from Java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I executed this SQL query in SQL developer successfully:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) "All",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) "Critical",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 END) "Info",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 END) "Warning",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 END) "Error"
FROM
    EVENT;
```

But when I try to execute the query this way i get error

```
dbRequest.setPreparedStatement("SELECT "
+ " COUNT(*) 'All',"
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) \"Critical\", "
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 END) \"Info\", "
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 END) \"Warning\", "
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 END) \"Error\" "
+ " FROM "
+ " EVENT");
```

Error:

```
SQL exception: Cannot get object 923: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Do you have any idea how i can fix this issue?

Comment: 'All' should be \"All\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up quotes in your request :

On line two, you must replace `''` by `"`

```
dbRequest.setPreparedStatement("SELECT "
+ " COUNT(*) \"All\","
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) \"Critical\", "
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 END) \"Info\", "
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 END) \"Warning\", "
+ " COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 END) \"Error\" "
+ " FROM "
+ " EVENT");
```